# :Telescope commands throw error

Tags: neovim

My environment:

- OS: OSX 11.6 BigSur
- nvim: 0.6

I had never used vim telescope before, so this is my first encounter with it.  I followed the instructions of installing telescope.nvim and plenary.nvim.

After this, I performed healthcheck, which seems good.

```
telescope: require("telescope.health").check()
========================================================================
## Checking for required plugins
  - OK: plenary installed.
  - OK: nvim-treesitter installed.

## Checking external dependencies
  - OK: rg: found ripgrep 13.0.0
  - OK: fd: found fd 8.3.0


## ===== Installed extensions =====
```

File: init.vim

```
     1  if empty(glob('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
     2    silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
     3      \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
     4    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
     5  endif
     6  
     7  " Plugins will be downloaded under the specified directory.
     8  call plug#begin()
     9  
    10  " Declare the list of plugins.
    11  "Plug 'bpstahlman/txtfmt'
    12  Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
    13  Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
    14  
    15  
    16  " For vsnip user.
    17  Plug 'hrsh7th/vim-vsnip-integ'
    18  Plug 'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets'
    19  Plug 'rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'
    20  Plug 'kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons'
    21  Plug 'folke/trouble.nvim'
    22  Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
    23  Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'
    24  Plug 'glepnir/spaceline.vim'
    25  Plug 'kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua'
    26  Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'
    27  Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'} 
    28  Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
    29  Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
    30  Plug 'neovim/nvim-lsp'
    31  Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
    32  Plug 'nvim-lua/diagnostic-nvim'
    33  Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'
    34  Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'
    35  Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'
    36  Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
    37  Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'
    38  " For vsnip user.
    39  Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-vsnip'
    40  Plug 'hrsh7th/vim-vsnip'
    41  Plug 'nvim-lua/popup.nvim'
    42  Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
    43  Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
    44  Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-icons'
    45  Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
    46  Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
    47  Plug 'chrisbra/unicode.vim'
    48  Plug 'bagrat/vim-buffet'
    49  " For showing a fancy homepage.
    50  Plug 'mhinz/vim-startify'
    51  
    52  " Use the icon plugin for better behavior
    53  Plug 'preservim/nerdtree' |
    54        \ Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin' |
    55        \ Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
    56  
    57  call plug#end()
    58  
    59  set completeopt=menu,menuone,noselect
    60  set encoding=UTF-8
    61  set ft=txtfmt
    62  autocmd VimEnter *
    63              \   if !argc()
    64              \ |   Startify
    65              \ |   NERDTree
    66              \ |   wincmd w
    67              \ | endif
    68  
    69  autocmd BufEnter * if &modifiable | NERDTreeFind | wincmd p | endif
    70  
    71  " Other regular settings
    72  set nu
    73  set ai
    74  set ts=2
    75  set et
    76  set nowrap
    77  set guifont=3270Medium\ Nerd\ Font\ Mono:h16
    78  set shiftwidth=2
    79  filetype plugin indent on
    80  syntax on
    81  "let g:txtfmtMapwarn = 'c'
    82  colorscheme solarized8_dark_flat
    83  set mouse=n
    84  "let g:indentLine_char = '|'
    85  let g:indentLine_char_list = ['|', '¦', '┆', '┊']
    86  
    87  let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|DS_Store\|git'
    88  
    89  " For source code folds
    90  "set foldmethod=indent   
    91  "set foldnestmax=10
    92  "set nofoldenable
    93  "set foldlevel=2
    94  
    95  
    96  set cursorline
    97  hi CursorLine   cterm=bold ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=white guibg=blue guifg=white
    98  hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=white guibg=darkred guifg=white
    99  :nnoremap <Leader>c :set cursorline! cursorcolumn!<CR>
   100  augroup CursorLineOnlyInActiveWindow
   101    autocmd!
   102    autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
   103    autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
   104  augroup END
   105  
   106  let g:NERDTreeGitStatusIndicatorMapCustom = {
   107                  \ 'Modified'  :'✹',
   108                  \ 'Staged'    :'✚',
   109                  \ 'Untracked' :'✭',
   110                  \ 'Renamed'   :'➜',
   111                  \ 'Unmerged'  :'═',
   112                  \ 'Deleted'   :'✖',
   113                  \ 'Dirty'     :'✗',
   114                  \ 'Ignored'   :'☒',
   115                  \ 'Clean'     :'✔︎',
   116                  \ 'Unknown'   :'?',
   117                  \ }
   118  
   119  let g:NERDTreeGitStatusUseNerdFonts = 1
   120  let g:NERDTreeGitStatusUntrackedFilesMode = 'all'
   121  let g:NERDTreeGitStatusShowClean = 1 " default: 0
   122  let g:vim_json_conceal=0
   123  
   124  " Git Gutter 
   125  highlight GitGutterAdd guifg=#009900 ctermfg=Green
   126  highlight GitGutterChange guifg=#bbbb00 ctermfg=Yellow
   127  highlight GitGutterChange guifg=#ff2222 ctermfg=Red
   128  nmap ) <Plug>(GitGutterNextHunk)
   129  nmap ( <Plug>(GitGutterPrevHunk)
   130  let g:gitgutter_enabled = 1
   131  set updatetime=250
   132  let g:gitgutter_max_signs = 500
   133  " No mapping
   134  let g:gitgutter_map_keys = 0
   135  " Colors
   136  let g:gitgutter_override_sign_column_highlight = 1
   137  "highlight clear SignColumn
   138  set signcolumn="yes:4"
   139  
   140  highlight GitGutterAdd ctermfg=2
   141  highlight GitGutterChange ctermfg=3
   142  highlight GitGutterDelete ctermfg=1
   143  highlight GitGutterChangeDelete ctermfg=4
   144  hi LspDiagnosticsVirtualTextError guifg=Red ctermfg=Red
   145  
   146  
   147  " close tag options
   148  " filenames like *.xml, *.html, *.xhtml, ...
   149  " These are the file extensions where this plugin is enabled.
   150  "
   151  let g:closetag_filenames = '*.html,*.xhtml,*.phtml,*.js'
   152  
   153  " filenames like *.xml, *.xhtml, ...
   154  " This will make the list of non-closing tags self-closing in the specified files.
   155  "
   156  let g:closetag_xhtml_filenames = '*.xhtml,*.jsx,*.js'
   157  
   158  " filetypes like xml, html, xhtml, ...
   159  " These are the file types where this plugin is enabled.
   160  "
   161  let g:closetag_filetypes = 'html,xhtml,phtml,javascript'
   162  
   163  " filetypes like xml, xhtml, ...
   164  " This will make the list of non-closing tags self-closing in the specified files.
   165  "
   166  let g:closetag_xhtml_filetypes = 'xhtml,jsx'
   167  
   168  " integer value [0|1]
   169  " This will make the list of non-closing tags case-sensitive (e.g. `<Link>` will be closed while `<link>` won't.)
   170  "
   171  let g:closetag_emptyTags_caseSensitive = 1
   172  " dict
   173  " Disables auto-close if not in a "valid" region (based on filetype)
   174  "
   175  let g:closetag_regions = {
   176      \ 'typescript.tsx': 'jsxRegion,tsxRegion',
   177      \ 'javascript.jsx': 'jsxRegion',
   178      \ 'typescriptreact': 'jsxRegion,tsxRegion',
   179      \ 'javascriptreact': 'jsxRegion',
   180      \ }
   181  
   182  " Shortcut for closing tags, default is '>'
   183  "
   184  let g:closetag_shortcut = '>'
   185  
   186  " Add > at current position without closing the current tag, default is ''
   187  let g:closetag_close_shortcut = '<leader>>'
   188  
   189  "runtime macros/matchit.vim
   190  
   191  
   192  let g:buffet_powerline_separators = 1
   193  let g:buffet_separator = '>'
   194  let g:buffet_show_index = 1
   195  
   196  nmap <leader>1 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(1)
   197  nmap <leader>2 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(2)
   198  nmap <leader>3 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(3)
   199  nmap <leader>4 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(4)
   200  nmap <leader>5 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(5)
   201  nmap <leader>6 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(6)
   202  nmap <leader>7 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(7)
   203  nmap <leader>8 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(8)
   204  nmap <leader>9 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(9)
   205  nmap <leader>0 <Plug>BuffetSwitch(10)
   206  
   207  
   208  " Spaceline customizations...
   209  let g:spaceline_separate_style = 'curve'
   210  let g:spaceline_colorscheme = 'dracula'
   211  command! -bang -nargs=* Rg call fzf#vim#grep("rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case ".shellescape(<q-args>), 1, {'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, <bang>0)
   212  
   213  set completeopt=menu,menuone,noselect
   214  
   215  lua require("lsp-config")
   216
```

But when I run any command such as `find_files`, I get a runtime error, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I am wondering, what I am missing here.  Do I need to configure anything else to get it properly working?

**Edit**

1. Performed `PlugUpdate`.  It did update some plugins.  But the Telescope error doesn't go away.
2. Adding the text version of the error:

```
E5108: Error executing lua ...ig/nvim/plugged/plenary.nvim//lua/plenary/popup/init.lua:408: Failed to switch to window 1007
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_set_current_win'
        ...ig/nvim/plugged/plenary.nvim//lua/plenary/popup/init.lua:408: in function 'create'
        ...g/nvim/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/pickers.lua:308: in function '_create_window'
        ...g/nvim/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/pickers.lua:378: in function 'find'
        .../plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/builtin/files.lua:268: in function 'v'
        .../plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/builtin/files.lua:614: in function 'v'
        ...m/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:508: in function <...m/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:479>
        ...g/nvim/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/command.lua:179: in function 'run_command'
        ...g/nvim/plugged/telescope.nvim//lua/telescope/command.lua:241: in function 'load_command'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Did you try to use `:PlugUpdate` to confirm all plug-ins are at the latest version?

Comment: Can you (also) paste the error message as text? Images are not very accessible, it's much easier for someone trying to help you here to copy and paste from text... Please [edit] the question to include that! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did your suggestions.  Error is still there.

Comment: cf. [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and trim down the vimrc that reproduces the problem. Consider also filing an issue with the plugin maintainers.